# Detecting touches on a scrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios4

Is it possible to detect the touches in a scrollview which is filled with a grid of buttons as in the image below?

[image]

For example, in this image, i can only drag the scroll view by dragging on the red areas, but i would like to be able to scroll the scrollview no matter where it is touched (like the iPhone's home screen)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.  Ironically enough, I had to do this last night.  In my case, I was embedding a `UIView` inside a `UIScrollView`, but I still wanted to detect taps and presses on my embedded view.  To do this, I enabled user interaction on the `UIView` and then attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to it.  It works beautifully. :)

Comment: So, since my buttons are UIButtons, and they are subclasses of UIView which have interaction enabled by default, i need to attach a TapRecognizer to each button to detect the taps and the LongPress to the scrollview? Or is the LongPress to the button as well? Thanks

Comment: It's possible that the UIButtons will work as-is.  If they don't, there are several ways around this (such as attaching a UIGR to the superview, disabling interaction on the buttons, and then using the hitTest: method to identify which button and alter it appropriately)

Comment: I think the buttons work fine now. My issue is going to be scrolling the scrollview. Do i add the long press to the scrollview or the button?

Comment: @joec my longpressGR was so I could detect a long press on one of my buttons (different from a tap).  Unless you also need the same functionality, you don't need that GR.

Comment: Ah ok, well i dont need that functionality. Were you able to detect the scrollview drags without doing anything?

Comment: I see i asked if it was possible. I must be missing something then for mine not to work?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but doesn't look like it was really answered.

You need to subclass UIScrollView and override `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:`. If you return YES, then the scroll view will scroll. (Somewhat confusing. I have trouble remembering whether the name of the method means cancel the scrolling, or cancel touching the other UI components. It means cancel touching the other UI components.)

If you want the buttons still to work, well, that might be more complicated.